# How to convert two consecutive elements from List to entries in Map in Dart?

Tags: dart

Same post as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800432/how-to-convert-two-consecutive-elements-from-list-to-entries-in-map), but I need the answer for Dart language.

I have a list:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

that I would like to to convert to the following map:

```
Map(1->2,3->4,5->6)
```

Which is the best way to implement this in dart?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a for loop, note that there might be more straightforward ways

```dart
  var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  var map = <int, int>{};
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i+=2) {
    map[list[i]] = list[i+1];
  }
  print(map); //{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

(Throws an error for odd lists)